# How to register aspect in spring application on non-spring-managed object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj

I have a spring mvc application running in JBoss. I am using Spring AOP all over the place (using Annotations); they are working perfectly. I want, however, to also create an aspect for a couple of JBoss classes (specifically their login JaaS stuff).

I have created a POJO within my application that looks like the following:

```
package com.mycompany.aspect
(all imports here)
@Aspect
public class MyAspect{
    @Pointcut("execution(* org.jboss.plugins.*.login(..))"
    private void myPointCut();

    @Around("myPointCut()")
    public Object doSomething(){....}
}
```

I have also created an aop.xml file in my META-INF directory that looks like the following:

```
<aspectj>
   <aspects>
       <aspect name="com.mycompany.aspect.MyAspect"/>
   </aspects>
   <weaver>
       <include within="org.jboss.plugins.*"/>
   </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

I have also added the following jvm option:

```
-javaagent:pathto/aspectjweaver.jar (pathto is the right path to my aspectjweaver.jar file)
```

When my application deploys I get the following RuntimeException:

> ..... cannot register non aspect com$mycompany$aspect$MyAspect, com.mycompany.aspect.MyAspect

What could I possibly be doing wrong???

EDIT: I should mention I am using JBoss AS (4.2)... This I cannot change :(